# What is the reasoning behind saying the magnetic field is non conservative

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, conservative-field

I remember hearing this and believing it but I cant seem to show it. If i consider a positive test charge moving around in a uniform magnetic field, then the field always seems to do no work. How can I go about reasoning that the work done in a magnetic field is path dependant and consequently there is no unique magnetic potential at a point?

Answer (score 0):

A vector field $\mathbf F$ is called conservative if there exists some scalar field $\psi$ such that $$\mathbf F = \nabla \psi$$

If $\mathbf F$ is conservative, then the fact that it is irrotational, i.e. $\nabla \times \mathbf F = \nabla \times (\nabla \psi) = 0$, follows immediately from the fact that the curl of a gradient always vanishes.  Equivalently, if the curl of a vector field $\mathbf F$ is *not* zero, then $\mathbf F$ is not conservative.

According to Faraday's law, though,

$$\nabla \times \mathbf B = \mu_0 \mathbf J + \epsilon_0 \mu_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf E}{\partial t}$$

so if the right hand side does not vanish, then $\mathbf B$ is not conservative.

---

It's also important to note that the converse holds only if the domain in question is [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space).  That is, the fact that $\nabla \times \mathbf B \neq 0$ does not generally imply that $\mathbf B$ is conservative.